# What do momentum matrix elements in energy basis represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

Suppose we have a Hamiltonian $H$ with eigenfunctions $\phi_1(\mathbf{x}),\ldots, \phi_n(\mathbf{x})$ and eigenvalues $E_1,\ldots, E_n$. What, if anything, does the matrix element

$$P_{mn} = \langle \phi_m | P| \phi_n\rangle  = -i\hbar\int  \overline{\phi_m}(\mathbf{x})\vec\nabla\phi_n(\mathbf{x})\,\,d^3x $$

represent?

> In the specific case of an electron in an atomic potential, my textbook (*Quantum Theory of Radiation* by E. Fermi) claims that this represents the momentum of the electron and it can immediately be proved that 
>   $$-i\hbar\int  \overline{\phi_m}(\mathbf{x})\vec\nabla\phi_n(\mathbf{x})\,\,d^3x = -im\nu_{mn}X_{nm}$$
>   where
>   $$\nu_{mn} = (E_m-E_n)/\hbar$$
>   and 
>   $$X_{mn} = X_{nm} = \int  \phi_n(\mathbf{x})\,\mathbf{X}\, \phi_m(\mathbf{x}) \,d^3x$$
>   where $\mathbf{X}$ is the position vector operator. I don't follow his claim.

Comment: What are the $u$ terms?

Comment: @AaronStevens edited; they should be $\phi$s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For single particle dynamics with Hamiltonian $H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$, it is clear that $[H,x] = [\frac{p^2}{2m},x] = i\hbar\frac{p}{m}$. Then taking matrix elements of both sides (in the energy eigenbasis $|n>$ with $H|n> = E_n|n>$) gives $<n|Hx|m> - <n|xH|m> = i\hbar P_{nm}$. The left hand side is $(E_n-E_m)X_{nm}$ so $\nu_{nm}X_{nm} = iP_{nm}$.